# why couldn't I use '__getattr__' like this in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, getattr, recursionerror

The code is like this, I want to use `__getattr__` to make class State useful that could
mount some properties on it, so that we could use it later, for example:

```
state = State()
state.name1 = 1
print(state.name1)
```

The complete code is like this:

```
class State:
    """
    提供给用户使用的 state；

    为了实现断点重训，用户应当保证其保存的信息都是可序列化的；

    # TODO：可能需要提供保存该state的函数，但是用户可以自己在 callback 里实现，现在我们先不管；
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self._value = dict()

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        self._value[key] = value

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        if item in self._value:
            return self._value[item]
        else:
            raise AttributeError(f"{self.__name__} has no attribute {item}.")

    def state_dict(self):
        return self._value

    def load_state_dict(self, value: dict):
        if not isinstance(value, dict):
            raise ValueError("If you want to reload a state dict for reasons like breakpoint retraining, this parameter"
                             "value should be a dict type.")
        self._value = value
```

And the traceback is like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "state.py", line 165, in <module>
a = State()
File "state.py", line 52, in __init__
self._value = dict()
File "state.py", line 55, in __setattr__
self._value[key] = value
File "state.py", line 58, in __getattr__
if item in self._value:
File "state.py", line 58, in __getattr__
if item in self._value:
File "state.py", line 58, in __getattr__
if item in self._value:
[Previous line repeated 993 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Answer (score -1):

To avoid the recursion between getattr and setattr functions, you have to call the parent setattr:

```py
def __setattr__(self, key, value):
    super().__setattr__(key, value)
    self._value[key] = value
```

Comment: Sorry for my late comment and thanks, very thankful for you guys' answers!!!